# What is Cov(X-Y,Z-W)

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

I know the equality of the covariance
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X+Y, Z+W) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,Z) + \operatorname{Cov}(X,W) + \operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z) + \operatorname{Cov}(Y,W),
$$
But I have the doubt that if it had negative signs then the equality would be
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X-Y, Z-W) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,Z) - \operatorname{Cov}(X,W) - \operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z) + \operatorname{Cov}(Y,W),
$$
I am not sure if this equality is true

Comment: It is true because Cov is linear in every argument.

Comment: To show why this linearity is true, do the simpler case of $Cov(X,aY)$ where $a$ is a real constant. Then you can combine what you know about adding the random variables with this about multiplying by constant coefficients to see linearity.

Comment: $\operatorname{Cov}(X, -Y) = \operatorname{Cov}(-X,Y) = -\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) $ so it is true

Answer (score 1):

It's true.

This is one of those cases where the definition is simple enough that you can trace it all through without getting hopelessly lost in the algebra. Using $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = \mathbb E[XY] - (\mathbb EX)(\mathbb E Y)$, which isn't quite the definition but a theorem you've probably encountered (and can probably prove if you haven't):

\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{Cov}(X-Y, Z-W) &= \mathbb E[(X-Y)(Z-W)] - \mathbb E[X-Y] \mathbb E[Z-W] \\
&= \mathbb E[XZ - XW - YZ + YW] - \left( \mathbb E X - \mathbb E Y \right) \left(\mathbb E Z - \mathbb E W \right)\\
&= \color{blue}{\mathbb E[XZ]} - \color{green}{\mathbb E[XW]} - \color{red}{\mathbb E[YZ]} + \mathbb E [YW]\\
& \qquad - \color{blue}{(\mathbb E X) (\mathbb E Z)} + \color{green}{(\mathbb E X)(\mathbb E W)} + \color{red}{(\mathbb E Y) (\mathbb E Z)} - (\mathbb E Y) (\mathbb E W)
\end{align*}
and grouping the terms in the last line by color shows that your last equality is true.